# Webpack Unexpected Token / no loader for filetype

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a plain JavaScript app that could not be build with WebPack. I removed everything until only those lines remain:

```
class MyClass {
    doStuff = (abc) => {

    }
}
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/mapdata.js 2:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class MyClass {
>     doStuff = (abc) => {
|
|     }
```

My webpack.config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/mapdata.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'rwmaps.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

I have no clue what the problem is. The JS is working fine if I access it directly from a web page (with ). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the babel loader and class properties. 
Try adding following dependencies in package.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.10.1",    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.1",    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
```

Also, create `.babelrc` and add following code:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Lastly, update webpack.config.js file with following rule:

```
    { test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }
      }
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick actually... Seems like webpack cannot do ES6.